# parse.com custom notification receiver

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm using a custom notification receiver class for parse.com push notifications to change the sound, vibration... sometimes, it looks to me that the notification did not arrives. I can see the push notification on the parse website as send. Maybe someone can review my code and see some wrong code pieces.

Manifest:

```
  <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

  <receiver
      android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />


          <category android:name="com.mflapp.test" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <receiver
      android:name=".MyCustomReceiver"
      android:exported="false" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
          <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
          <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

MyCustomReceiver

```
public class MyCustomReceiver  extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;


    protected void onPushReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {

        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE")) {
                NOTIFICATION_ID++;
                String title = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
                if (json.has("alert"))
                {
                    String text = json.getString("alert");
                    generateNotification(mContext, title, json, text);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }


    private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, JSONObject json, String text) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, home.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationManager mNotifM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(text)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text))
                        .setTicker(text)
                        .setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotifM.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: no one with any idea? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing an @Override note at all?
The signature of the method should be:

```
@Override 
protected void onPushReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent)
```

When I have had problems with notifications, I have added a line: 
android:name=".MyApplication" to the application tag in the Android manifest and it helped me.

Also I'm not sure that yours numerating system is good. When you relaunch app, counting starts from 1 again. I suppose that you are using notification id while showing it for users and now it didn't work.